# Should I put built C++ libs in /opt/local/lib or /usr/lib on OSX

Tags: macos

I'm building libraries using clang from Xcode 4.6 to build for OS/X and iOS developers.

I want to recommend the most common place but have found inconsistency amongst different open source libraries. Those with a "make install" seem to put in /usr/local but there are more libraries in /opt/local/lib. I haven't been able to find any Apple documentation covering this issue.

thanks

Comment: `/opt/local` is managed by [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org), and only software installed through MacPorts should go in there.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't used MacPorts in so long I hadn't realised that it created that. This stuff is annoyingly difficult to search for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to take a look at [Framework Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/InstallingFrameworks.html) and [Dynamic Library Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/conceptual/dynamiclibraries/100-Articles/UsingDynamicLibraries.html). For the static/dynamic libs I think the right choice will be the `/usr/local`.

Comment: Thanks cody especially for the link. I wanted to give people a standard location for the static library even though it's somewhat irrelevant.